# HTML/CSS: Aligning contents within divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

How do I align elements within a `</div>` using the `align` attribute like for example in the below image:

[image: naaaa]

- **e1**:`align="top"`
- **e2**:`align="right"`
- **e3**:`align="bottom"`
- **e4**:`align="left"`

**EDIT**: So for in this case, it isn't clear what I want to tell. This is not a homework or anything else, just wanted to learn HTML / CSS myself. I was just asking **if** it is possible to achieve this using only `align` attribute.

Hope this code snippets in the thing I am making will help you to understand what I really want to achieve:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="nav-vbar">
    <button class="btnV" align="top"></button>
    <button class="btnV" align="bottom"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
    </div>

    <div id="nav-hbar">
    <button class="btnH" align="left"></button>
    <button class="btnH" align="right"></button>
    </div>

    <div id="preview">
    </div>

</div>
```

The result what I'm trying to work `(grayed divs are in focus)`

[image]

Comment: Please show you current HTML that attempts this. Is is not clear which part exactly you are having trouble with

Comment: Why not just `margin`?

Comment: I think you should start **[here](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/30-days-to-learn-html-and-css-a-free-tuts-premium-course/)**

Comment: @stackular Well I try that but I was looking for an organize way without too much manual calculation.

Comment: @mr5: Are you attempting to vertically and horizontally center your content?

Comment: http://codeacademy.com

Answer (score 1):

First of all don't use the align attribute.  To that extent I'm not even sure you would be able to manage this using it.  You should be using CSS and floats or even inline-block.

To that extent, you should take a look at [Code Academy](http://www.codeacademy.com).  They have free web tutorials on HTML, CSS, and much more.  They arent just some reading either, there is actual practice involved.

Now...  I'm not going to give you a fully working set of HTML/CSS, as just about no one else here will do, and none of us should.  This place is for helping you solve problems.  A lack of knowledge is not a problem with code.  Do some work and googling and some simple experimentation to try this on your own.  When you run into an actual problem come back and let us know.

That said, to achieve this structure, you need 4 div's to manage the primary 3 column layout.  A parent, and 3 children.  One div wraps all the rest and would be considered a "wrapper" or "container".  The first of the other 3 divs is your left column, the second div is another wrapper which contains 3 more divs (e1, e3 and your white space in the middle), then the third div is your right column.

Using float left will align them all next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use the `align` attribute. It's obsolete. You can better use CSS.
You will need to create at least three parent `<div>`s.

You can do something like:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="e4">
    </div>

    <div class="middle">

        <div class="e1">
        </div>

        <div></div>

        <div class="e3">
        </div>

    </div>

    </div class="e2">
    </div>

</div>
```

And then add styles for them

Styles can be like

```
.wrapper {

}

.e4 {
float: left;
}

.e2 {
float: right;
}

.e1 {
display: block;
}

.e3 {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have content inside them and specify the widths/heights too if you can (if the layout is fixed).

Comment: @Michael Oops. Thought he's lost or something.

Comment: John, you'll learn soon enough by reading many posts like this who has an actual problem and who knows 0 about html.  Most of the time they are either in some class they dont want to take and dont want to learn basic HTML and CSS, or they are people who want a website and cant do it themselves, cant pay to have it done, and so they make questions like this to get snippets of code.  Best thing to do in these cases is to encourage them to try on their own and come back when they have an actual problem with code and not a lack of know-how.

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I didn't really know that. I'm new here myself as well. I'll follow your approach from next time. Thanks.

Comment: No need to say sorry, I can tell your new from your rep, hence the comment ;)  Some other people here would just jump down your throat and yell at you because they are on here at work because they hate their jobs.  Figured I'd get in on it before someone did that to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace 500px and 200px with whatever you need.

```
<div style="width: 500px;height: 200px;margin: 0 auto;display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;height: 100%;text-align: center;">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a bit difficult to understand what you want from that sketch. Give me some feedback on how close this is. Because from what I see, you could very well use something like this:

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <div style="position: absolute;top: 50px;right: 100px;bottom: 50px;left: 100px;text-align: center">
        content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to be more explicit...